# Conditional pagination using DynamoDB scan

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a list of people that all have the field `cityName`:

```
Person {
  id: ...
  name: ...
  cityName: ...
}
```

I would like to paginate through the list using the DynamoDB operators `Limit` and `ExclusiveStartKey`. This works just fine, but I run into trouble when I want to paginate users coming from, fx, 'London'

`cityName: 'London'`

I have tried to add the following:

```
FilterExpression: 'cityName = :x',
ExpressionAttributeValues: {
  ':x': 'London'
}
```

But this simply removes the *non-matching* people **after** the scan has completed. I want to filter **before** the scan occurs.

Is there any way for me to achieve this?

Comment: By design, the filter is applied after the scan and it can't be controlled by API at the moment. You can consider using GSI.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the `query` method is the right for the approach. All `scan` filtering is done **after** the fetch from the database and would therefore never work.

I hope this can help others out:

```
const cityName = 'London'

const params = {
  TableName: 'Person',
  Limit: 5,
  IndexName: 'cityName-index',
  KeyConditionExpression: 'cityName = :x',
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ':x': cityName
  }
}

// For pagination add the "ExclusiveStartKey" key to params
```